# How can I take a screenshot of scene with childrens in a particular camera positions even after moving the scene of HTML page in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, three.js

In an HTML page using Three.js, I developed a scene of a product which contains multiple GLTFLoader childrens. The product parts can be updated. How can I take a screenshot of a product in a particular camera position even after it moved or rotated?

The screenshot should contain the product maximum size.

```
function toDataURL(strMime){
    let curVector = camera.position.clone();
    // camera.up - test
    // let worldDir = camera.getWorldDirection();
    // var vector = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, -1 );
    // vector.applyQuaternion( camera.quaternion );
    // let camTarget = camera.target.position.clone();
    // let curMatrix = camera.matrix.clone();
    let vector = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, - 1 );
    console.log('curVector',camera.clone());
    vector.applyQuaternion( camera.clone().quaternion );
    camera.position.set( - 2.8, 1.0, - 3.7 );
    camera.lookAt(0,0,0);
    render();
    let imgData = renderer.domElement.toDataURL(strMime);
    camera.position.set( curVector.x, curVector.y, curVector.z );
    camera.lookAt(0,0,0);
    render();
    console.log('after camera', camera)
    return imgData;
}
```

the image taken not viable because the distance of the scene is too far from from camera or the scene is too small, the distance of the scene is too short or the scene is too large, how can set camera such that image of the scene in the canvas and not too small but inside the canvas, also camera take square image?

Comment: What's wrong with the above code? It seems to be working fine. https://codepen.io/cdeep/pen/dyVKOEo?editors=0011

Comment: scene resize depending on canvas size, i want image with 500 height 500 width, sometimes image of scene is larger or too small, while taking image. is there any way zoom upto minimum height or width get square image

Comment: @Vrithanth M K: Can you [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70578857/edit) the appropriate information to the question, please? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question should appear as if it was written right now).